# Send input with array in angular 5

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, input, angular5

in normal html we can do that:

```
<input name="xyz[]" value="Lorem" />
<input name="xyz[]" value="ipsum"  />
<input name="xyz[]" value="dolor" />
<input name="xyz[]" value="sit" />
<input name="xyz[]" value="amet" />
```

and the result is array sent to the server. 
how can i do that in angular 5 ?

it's not working the same way also not working in ngModel.

Comment: Just because you can, doesn't mean you should ;) What is your goal ? Infinite loop, or you have an array length ?

Comment: I already have length and I use it in angular like that . [(ngModel)]="xyz[i]" but this isn't work

Comment: I'm making you an answer, wait a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used angular Form Group and this was the solve for this problem :

```
<div ngModelGroup="xyz">
    <input name="1" ngModel />
    <input name="2" ngModel />
    <input name="3" ngModel />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never used it, but can't you use an index?

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="xyz[0]" />
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="xyz[1]" />
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="xyz[2]" />
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="xyz[3]" />
```

I have seen this in this [github's issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10423).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a length on your array, you can either use reactive forms with a **[FormArray](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#use-formarray-to-present-an-array-of-formgroups)**, or use template-driven forms. Since you stated using the latter one, here is how you should do it :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of xyz; let i = index; trackBy: myCustomTrackBy">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="xyz[i]">
</ng-container>
```

In your Typescript :

```
myCustomTrackBy(index, item) { return index; }
```